# Run Rest API via PowerShell in order to get the current sprint

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to run this script and store in variable and then do $y.value and I get all the sprints for this team.
(past,current,future). The goal is to get the current sprint number and store it
How can I do that?

```
$y = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/Idu Client-Server/SRE/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=current&api-version=5.0"
$y.value
```

The results are:

```
id         : 760c925c-db3c-4d81-be19-485027a09d93
name       : Sprint 72
path       : Idu Client-Server\Sprints\Sprint 72
attributes : @{startDate=2022-02-27T00:00:00Z; finishDate=2022-03-17T00:00:00Z; timeFrame=past}
url        : https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/17944823-be9c-40ea-b970-2a2989d6ddd4/15a27310-2250-4786-a935-946b0dccf206/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/760c925c-db3c-4d81-be19-485027a09d93

id         : 8a9987cb-fb2d-4de2-8db8-5303cc7748e5
name       : Sprint 73
path       : Idu Client-Server\Sprints\Sprint 73
attributes : @{startDate=2022-03-20T00:00:00Z; finishDate=2022-04-07T00:00:00Z; timeFrame=current}
url        : https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/17944823-be9c-40ea-b970-2a2989d6ddd4/15a27310-2250-4786-a935-946b0dccf206/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/8a9987cb-fb2d-4de2-8db8-5303cc7748e5

id         : ab3c4a30-8141-4923-82cf-067b5d0aaed3
name       : Sprint 74
path       : Idu Client-Server\Sprints\Sprint 74
attributes : @{startDate=2022-04-10T00:00:00Z; finishDate=2022-04-28T00:00:00Z; timeFrame=future}
url        : https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/17944823-be9c-40ea-b970-2a2989d6ddd4/15a27310-2250-4786-a935-946b0dccf206/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/ab3c4a30-8141-4923-82cf-067b5d0aaed3
```

Comment: Do you just want the highest integer value of name? So get all names, split with space (keep only last), sort and take the last value?

Comment: Yes I want only the highest integer of the current sprint, I don’t know how to that .. this is why I asked this question maybe there is a easiest way?

Comment: Why I get all the sprints if I do =current?

Comment: To answer that "=current" problem: it might be that you did not want $timeframe to be interpreted as PowerShell variable. If so, please replace the doublequotes with singlequotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the api you are using and i don't have access to it. But here is a PowerShell script that can filter the data in your $y variable.

EDIT: Updated Version

```
$APIUri = "https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/Idu%20Client-Server/SRE/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?timeframe=current&api-version=5.0"
$APIData = (Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $APIUri).Value
$CurrentAPIObject = $APIData |where {($_.attributes).timeFrame -eq "current"}
$null, [int]$CurrentSprintInteger = $CurrentAPIObject.Name -split " "
```

Dirty short version:

```
[int](($y.value |where {($_.attributes).timeFrame -eq "current"}).Name -split " ")[-1]
```

Comment: Maybe you have a better way to get this value without using the rest api

Comment: Your script returned the latest sprint. I need only the current sprint and only the integer
This what I got:
id         : 561eac18-ee14-4df0-b261-cd2057482ed6
name       : Sprint 76
path       : Idu Client-Server\Sprints\Sprint 76
attributes : @{startDate=2022-05-22T00:00:00Z; finishDate=2022-06-09T00:00:00Z; timeFrame=future}
url        : https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/17944823-be9c-40ea-b970-2a2989d6ddd4/15a27310-2250-4786-a935-946b0dccf206/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/561eac18-ee14-4df0-b261-cd2057482ed6
sprint     : 76

Comment: Why this is not working?

$y.value | Select-Object name | where {$_.attributes -like "current"}

Comment: I think this will do the job right?

($y.value | Select-Object name,attributes | Where-Object {$_.attributes -match "current"}).name

Comment: What result do you expect? I cannot access the domain as my DNS cannot resolve it. So i need your input to be detailled. Are there always 3 results in your $y ? Do you always want the middle one? The result example does not seem to have anything named "current"

Comment: You cannot access to this url, I got many results…if you look you will find that one of them holds timeFrame=current the one I need. Need to find the current a get only the sprint number

Comment: Updated my answer with a second try comment